# Ugly tab delimited text file I want to "normalise", attempting it via SQL

Tags: sql, csv

I have a huge text file of something like 11 million rows, I cant change this but I would like to be able to process it into a usable format. It is basically structured as:

```
Field1 : Type of data
Field2 : Values
```

There is also a ### to mark the start and end of a product in the file (still, not sure that will help me)

Within the data is something like 200,000 unique products, and all data associated with it. The Field1 values will repeat (e.g. PRODUCT, PRICE, DESCRIPTION), and the values will be different to identify the attributes of the products. I imported the tab delimited file into Access and used SQL to pull data that I needed (a full list of all the products) but it would be very helpful to be able to process it further and have all the parts listed as one column, followed by say price, description etc

The Query I ran to pull the products out was:

```
select 
Field1, 
Field2 
from Index 
where Field1 = 'PRODUCT';
```

This gives me the list of all PRODUCTS

I am not confident extending the above would be the right approach as if I extend it to (and excuse the syntax, I have had to have a bash at SQL just to get this far)

```
select 
Field1, 
Field2 
from Index 
where Field1 = 'PRODUCT'
and Field1 = 'PRICE';
```

(If I got that to work, which i am sure it does not) I would be in much the same position as I would just get

```
Product
Price
Product
Price
x200000
```

What I would like to do is have :

```
Product   Price    Description
11111      1.11     This is part 1
11112      1.12     This is part 2
```

I did look for examples of similar, but I guess people are used to working with better input files...
Oh, from what I did see SSIS may be the key? Again, never played with that yet so completely new to it, and want to see if this is possible via SQL.

Thanks muchly

example :

```
###
PRODUCT A1000102
SHORT_DESC  SMALL COG
PRICE   1.15
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   B
###
PRODUCT A1000103
SHORT_DESC  MEDIUM COG
PRICE   1.18
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   B
ROTATION    YES
###
PRODUCT A1000104
SHORT_DESC  L COG
PRICE   1.15
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   2
###
PRODUCT A1000105
SHORT_DESC  TITANIUM COG
PRICE   4.12
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   B
###
PRODUCT A1000106
SHORT_DESC  SMALL TITANIUM COG
PRICE   1.15
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   A
COLOUR  BLUE
###
PRODUCT A1000107
SHORT_DESC  SMALL COG
PRICE   1.15
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   C
COUNTRY SWISS
###
PRODUCT A1000108
SHORT_DESC  SMALL COG
PRICE   1.15
RANDOM_ASSOCIATED   X
WEIGHT  9.54KG
###
```

Comment: A sample of the raw file may help

Comment: Just opening a text file with 11 million rows in to take the sample gives me a headache. I will extract manually a set of a few products. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Edit your question and put that sample in there

Comment: Is this for a one time job? Are there any CR/LF's in the input file? If both are true, I would suggest to first load it into excel, add a row header, remove redundant columns and upload the result to a SQL Server.

Comment: Lievn, It does not have CR/LF and would be enourmous to load to excell surely?

Comment: Gordon, excuse my limited knowledge, would that not get me to the same place as having this available via the access database?

Comment: Is this a one off?  There are unique fields for some products; COUNTRY /COLOR/ROTATION how many can there be per product? do you want them in separate columns?

Comment: It is likely something I would like to run again, the mix of products will change over time, and I can get a new output text file, load to access and ideally qry through SQL for updated data. Its 200k products, I may have 10k with colour, but if I get the method for formatting it as columns for PRODUCT, PRICE and DESCRIPTION I can add any addition as and when required (Colour for example) - does that make sense? And it is up to ~50 fields on some products.

Comment: Hi Alex, 
If I could run it for the "core" fields, I can copy the syntax to add more columns if necessary. And yes, I would like them to have their own columns.

Comment: Presented with this problem, I wouldn't immediately think "I'll use TSQL to solve that." Each product has a number of attributes but, do you have finite list of all possibilities and the types?

Comment: If you are able to retain and repeat the productnr value, it is trivial to convert the file to EAV form with records {productnr,attributeName,AttributeValue}. This could be in any programming language, but awk seems a natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my advice:  First, use bulk insert to load the data into a SQL table.  Then use SQL queries to extract the data in whatever format you may like for secondary tables.

Why do I suggest this:

1. If there are errors loading the original data, for some reason, you can isolate those and fix them.
2. If you change your mind on your data structure after looking at the data, you can do so just by changing queries.
3. If you need to repeat the process, you can save everything at t-sql statements to be run or modified later.
4. If you have a multiprocessor machine, the database should maximize the use of resources.

If you need to maintain row order in the loaded table, then you can do that by using a view.  Create the table as something like:

```
create table DirtyData (
    DirtyData_id int identity(1,1),
    KeyNamevarchar(255),
    Value varchar(255)
);

create view v_DirtyData as
    select KeyName, Value
    from DirtyData;
```

Then bulk insert into the view, rather than directly into the table.  The id will be assigned monotonically.

Comment: Hopefully, the load utility retains row order, or the OP would end up in a _worse_ position.

Comment: #after edit# - This assumes the bulk insert will be inserting in order.  If you multi-thread the process, I bet against you.

Comment: I admit to using this trick mostly to just add an id to the table, not a sequential id specifically in the original order (although it usually does that).  You might come closer to guaranteeing the order by setting BUFFER_SIZE = 1, in the import.  There is an interesting discussion of this here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/278452/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-preserve-order-when-bulk-loading-a-file.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the replies, I am going to have to spend some time learning to insert it seems. Wish me luck, and many thanks. Will feedback if I crack this or otherwise.